# Razor variable inside string html helper parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here's may Html helper:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("CONTACT THE USER ABOUT THIS LISTING", "create", "contactform", new { recipientID = Model.User.Id, productid = Model.Product.ID }, null)
```

What I would like to do is:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("CONTACT " Model.UserName " ABOUT THIS LISTING", "create", "contactform", new { recipientID = Model.User.Id, productid = Model.Product.ID }, null)
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate string values in C#:

```
"CONTACT " + Model.UserName + " ABOUT THIS LISTING"
```

Or something like `string.Format()` instead:

```
string.Format("CONTACT {0} ABOUT THIS LISTING", Model.UserName)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I could not get any result just because Model.UserName in this case does not take any value. so I kept thinking I was doing something wrong.. how silly of me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use standard string concantenation.

```
@Html.ActionLink("CONTACT " + Model.UserName + " ABOUT THIS LISTING", "create", "contactform", new { recipientID = Model.User.Id, productid = Model.Product.ID }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink($"CONTACT {Model.UserName} ABOUT THIS LISTING", "create", "contactform", new { recipientID = Model.User.Id, productid = Model.Product.ID }, null)
```